# how to convert int variable into ascii words

Tags: c++

good afternoon everybody, i have some problem in my program, i want to convert the int variable into ascii words. But when i compile it, it only print out the first word only. here is my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int progd1=72, progd2=69, progd3=76, progd4=76, progd5=79;
    char H=progd1, E=progd2, L=progd3, l=progd4, O=progd5;
    cout<<"\nknown :ascii1=72\n";
    cout<<"         ascii2=69\n";
    cout<<"         ascii3=76\n";
    cout<<"         ascii4=76\n";
    cout<<"         ascii5=79\n";
    cout<<"\nIf all that variable spliced together, "
    <<"\nthen the program will form into ASCII, that is "<<H,E,L,l,O;
    getch();
}
```

When I compile it, it only prints out the H word.

Comment: Why do you have a C# tag for something that appears to have nothing to do with C#? I suspect the problem is simply that `,` doesn't do what you expect it to here... but this isn't C# and I don't think it's C either.

Comment: @JonSkeet im sorry, my mistake

Comment: Just replace the `,` with `<<`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ῥεῖ its just worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply each of your variables to cout using the insertion operator (<<):

```
cout << "\n If all that variable spliced together ..." <<H<<E<<L<<l<<O;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `,` doesn't do what you think it does. `a,b` means to evaluate `a`, then evaluate `b`, then use the result of `b` (so e.g. `(1+1, 2*3)` is 6).

```
cout<<"\nIf all that variable spliced together, "<<"\nthen the program will form into ASCII, that is "<<H,E,L,l,O;
```

This statement evaluates `cout<<"\nIf all that variable spliced together, "<<"\nthen the program will form into ASCII, that is "<<H`. Then it evaluates `E` and doesn't do anything with the result, then it evaluates `L` and doesn't do anything with the result, and so on.

You already know how to print multiple things - keep chaining `<<` operators. `cout<<...<<H<<E<<L<<l<<O;`.

Comment: it works! thank you very much (y)